# Trying to install OCFS2 on Ubuntu 16.04: o2cb command not found

Tags: ubuntu, filesystems, ocfs2

What I did so far:

installed all ocfs2-related packages (ocfs2-tools, ocfs2-tools-dev and ocfs2console).

I try to setup an OCFS2 file system using the o2cb cluster registration utitity so to use command like

```
o2cb add-cluster ocfs2demo
o2cb add-node --ip 10.0.0.1 --port 7777 --number 1 ocfs2demo ocfs2-1 
o2cb add-node --ip 10.0.0.2 --port 7777 --number 2 ocfs2demo ocfs2-2 
o2cb add-node --ip 10.0.0.3 --port 7777 --number 3 ocfs2demo ocfs2-3 
o2cb register-cluster ocfs2demo
o2cb start-heartbeat ocfs2demo
```

This is the recommended way (instead of editing the config files manually).

Problem is I don't find the o2cb command on my machine after I install the above mentioned packages. Also did a system-wide search for a o2cb binary missing in my path using updatedb/locate o2cb but I don't find an executable.
There is the init script and the /sbin/o2cb_ctl control program but that's about it...

Do I need to install anything else to be able to execute o2cb commands to populate the config files?

Thanks in advance!